# Quick algorithm of comparing sums of two arrays?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting

Suppose I have 2 integer arrays, they could be not in same length and value on any index is a valid integer (min ~ max). such as:

```
int data1[] = {1227210749, 382745290, 567552295, 1910060611,
           577735884, 75518037, 742485551, 1202127013, 
           386030509, 308032134};

int data2[] = {1729472635, 1258098863, 259427472, 1664987257, 
           994376913, 1581883691, 1728724734, 2034013490};
```

How could I quickly compare of them to know which one have a bigger sum?

```
int compare(int a[], int len_a, int b[], int len_b)
{
    // compares if the sum of data1 is bigger than sum of data2
}
```

Comment: [No homework?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework)

Comment: @Domi At last definitely not in this "pl0x do me my houmworkz!!!" style...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious way is just to take the sum of both arrays and see which is larger. Something like so:

```
int compare(int a[], int len_a, int b[], int len_b)
{
    return (std::accumulate(a, a+len_a, 0) - std::accumulate(b, b+len_b, 0);
}
```

However, this introduces the possibility of integer overflow. This can be avoided by changing the last parameter of `accumulate` to `0LL` or `0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively (which is pretty weak in my case I guess, I'm *not* an algorithms expert) this feels as if won't be possible without looking at each number once, and simply computing the sum. This is since integers are signed, the sum of an array can become 0 (or negative) when adding any element, so you have to look at all of them.

So, try to implement a function like this:

```
int int_array_sum(const int *array, size_t num_elements);
```

then simply call that on each of the two arrays, and compare.

Edit: as pointed out in [Tristan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20116775/28169) there's a risk of overflow when adding potentially large integers. If this is a problem (that's really quite application-spefific, perhaps overflow results is part of "having a larger sum") you can switch to a wider integer type, or go with `double`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int compare( int a[], int len_a, int b[], int len_b )
{
    long long sum_a = std::accumulate( a, a + len_a, 0ll );
    long long sum_b = std::accumulate( b, b + len_b, 0ll );

    return ( sum_a < sum_b ? -1 : ( sum_a == sum_b ? 0 : 1 ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int compare(int a[], int len_a, int b[], int len_b)
{
  double sum1=0;
double sum2=0;

for(int i=0;i<len_a;i++)
sum1=sum1+a[i];

for(int i=0;i<len_b;i++)
sum2=sum2+b[i];

if( sum1>sum2)
return 1;
else 
return 0;

}
```